# How can I copy all files which starts with "b" or "B" from /bin to a specific folder?

Tags: command-line

How can I copy all files which starts with "b" or "B" from /bin to a specific folder?

I tried `cp /bin* b` , but I didn't succeed.

Comment: `cp /bin/b* /to_folder/` should work

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use:

```
cp /bin/[bB]* ~/tolocation
```

Comment: Anyone care to say why the -1?

Comment: Saw the -1 very briefly - it is gone now.

Comment: i'd rather "cp -p" than just "cp" ...

Comment: I prefer to use `cp /bin/[bB]* ~/tolocation/`, to ensure that ~/tolocation is a directory and not a file.

Comment: When I did this I got the error No such file or directory. If you also get this error, try the other answer because it worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

The right command is:

```
cp /bin/b* /bin/B* destination
```

You will probably get this error:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/bin/B*’: No such file or directory
```

That's because there should be no files starting with 'B'. However you shouldn't worry.